# AS3 - Compare a value of a string variable with a value contained in a text field

Tags: actionscript-3, types, casting

I can not compare a value of a string variable with a value contained in a text field.
I entered "Hello World" in the text box then I click on the button
The expected result is "identical", and I get "different."

```
var monTexte:String = "Hello World";
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (monTexte==monTexteSaisie.text) trace ("identique");
    else trace("différent");
}
```

Comment: Then you probably didn't type in the very same text, otherwise that condition has to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `.toLowerCase()` function, to make checking easier. Or try using `texfField.text.indexOf(variableText)` to check if the text is there.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a newline

```
 trace("-"+monTexteSaisie.text+"-")
```

Answer (score -1):

You must remove a checkbox in the flash file. "Crenage automique" sory my version of flash is in french. Just beside the place where you change the color of the text.